# Failure on "session_register" command in php while using with sqlsrv azure

Tags: php, azure

I have such an index.php page;

```
<?php
include("Config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
// username and password sent from Form 
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']); 
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT ID, username, password FROM login WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=sqlsrv_query($bd, $sql);
$row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=sqlsrv_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
session_register("myusername");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: website/index.php");
}
else 
{
$error="Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
```

I cannot understand what is wrong, there is no connection problem,

there is no problem in reading data from the html form,

but still when I click login, it comes to the same page, does not go "website/index.php".

If there is a problem in `session_register`, what can be the alternative?

How can I manage it?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: try to debug your code. echo you sql statement. check that it comes inside the `if($count==1)` condition. also user `exit;` after call `header("location...);`

Comment: Okay, Satish, I'm trying now.

Comment: there can be one more issue that it will going on the `website/index.php` but there is some checking you applied (eg. user authentication which redirect back to login page). check it also.

Comment: I've implemented your idea like this, Satish; if($count==1)
{
echo $sql["username"];
session_register("myusername");
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: website/index.php");
exit;
}, but nothing is written on the screen.

Comment: No, Satish, there is nothing which redirects me to the main index.php page. At the beginning of website/index.php page, there is such a code; <?php
include("/site/wwwroot/lock.php");
?><?php echo $login_session; ?>, but I cannot see the website/index.php page.

Comment: Satish, I've checked again now. And I see there is no problem in fetching data from sql. It prints.

Comment: now check that r u giving correct path in `header("location:...");`

Comment: Satish, I've determined the problem. The problem is with session_register. Do you know what is its alternative? Because when I use it, I see a blank page. When I remove it, I get the message "This web page has a redirect loop."

Comment: alternative is use session array for store data in session  as already you have done like `$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;`

Comment: so, there is no need to do more, hmm?

Comment: But can you look at lock.php; http://codepaste.net/g4yz7b. lock.php is included in website/index.php. At the beginning... probably the problem is here.

Comment: Satish, I've solved the problem in lock.php I couldn't realize that I wrote wrong table name, it should be login, not admin :D Now the turn is solving the other problem :D

Comment: The next problem, Satish, in website/index.php page. I gave ../logout.php this link to "logout" button. It goes, no problem,  http://misbounstash.azurewebsites.net/logout.php, but still nothing happens. I cannot come to the main index.php page.

Comment: check the code of `logout.php`

Comment: <?php
session_start();
if(session_destroy())
{
header("Location: index.php");
}
?> This is all the code in logout.php

Comment: `<?php session_start(); session_destroy(); header("location: index.php"); ?>`

Comment: Still the same problem, Satish...

Comment: `echo "something";` on your logout.php

Comment: Nooo, still the same problem... Nothing is written.

Comment: same problem? means its echo something or not on logout.php? or its redirecting on this page or not.

Comment: I'm sorry Satish. :) It doesn't echo "something", anything. it is on logout.php. But still on the page which is "logout.php" called from.

Comment: first tell me its redirecting on logout.php or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54337/discussion-between-satish-sharma-and-hasan-sait-arslan).

Comment: Satish, it doesn't make a redirection. But also stays in the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alternative is use session array for store data in session as already you have done like

`$_SESSION['myusername']=$myusername;`

**Note:** I have already commented the this answer. but i am giving this as an answer post so that this question may not be listed in unanswered because OP's problem has been solved as commented below question.

Comment: Thank you Satish, again. :)